# Roles in Microsoft azure not logging to WADLogsTable

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

I currently have 3 roles running on azure and am wanting to monitor the output of the Windows Azure Diagnostics.  I am looking in the WADLogsTable in the relevant storage table that the roles are, or should be, logging against.
My problem is this;-  2 of my roles, let's call them 'API' and 'Service' are logging fine to the WADLogsTable.  My 3rd role, called 'TheRest' is only logging certain events, in fact the only 2 messages it is logging is:-

> EventName="DirectWrite" Message="Getting "StorageQueueEncryptionKey"
> from ConfigurationManager: PASS."
>
> EventName="DirectWrite"
> Message="Getting "StorageQueueEncryptionKey" from ServiceRuntime:
> FAIL."

I've tried making the wadcgfx files on TheRest have the exact same values as the 2 working roles, and updating the relevant diagnostics and running through my test cases.

Any ideas on how to get better details from the non working role?

Answer (score 0):

This could indicate that the diagnostics agent was not able to correctly get the key to write to the storage account when it was enabled. 
How did you publish the role through Visual Studio/PowerShell? Can you try publishing them again or simply update the diagnostics extension using powershell

```
$service_name = "MyService"
$diagnostics_storagename = "myservicediagnostics"
$webrole_diagconfigpath = "MyService.WebRole.PubConfig.xml" 
$primary_storagekey = (Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName "$diagnostics_storagename").Primary
$storage_context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $diagnostics_storagename -StorageAccountKey $primary_storagekey

Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storage_context -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $webrole_diagconfigpath -ServiceName $service_name -Slot Production -Role "WebRole"
```

Alternatively you can also use Visual Studio Server Explorer - Right click on the Role and select Update Diagnostics. In the dialog that pops up make sure the diagnostics storage account is set correctly and click ok to apply the settings. This should force an update and set the diagnostics storage account correctly.

Hope that helps.